# Automatic brightness missing from settings in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, laptop, brightness, system-settings

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on my Thinkpad T495s and I wanted to enable adaptive brightness. However, the automatic brightness is missing from my Settings/Power. 
[image: My Settings/Power]

I tried to google and found this [article](https://itsfoss.com/automatic-brightness-ubuntu/) which mentioned using 
 `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled true`
to enable automatic brightness but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ways to fix the system settings? I'm also open to using third-party apps if I can't use the system settings.

Comment: did you find any solution. If so could you please add it as an answer here

Comment: Also seeing this on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a frame.work laptop.

Comment: This fixed me on 22.04 LTS: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405073/22-04-jammy-shows-no-brightness-sliders-under-settings-power