# 22.04 jammy shows no brightness sliders under Settings > Power

Tags: brightness, settings, 22.04

Is this an intentional change in 22.04 LTS?  Or is something just not recognizing the hardware correctly?  Previously, I had both a **Screen Brightness** and **Keyboard Brightness** slider visible under **Settings > Power**.  Those no longer appear in 22.04 LTS.  BTW: I tried disabling the **Automatic Screen Brightness** (especially since my device doesn't support the capability) but that didn't cause any sliders to be revealed.

21.10 impish [image: 21.10 "impish"]
22.04 LTS jammy [image: 22.04 LTS "jammy"]

Answer (score 2):

For me this happened upgrading from 22.10 => 23.04

All the brightness controls went missing and the brightness keys on the laptop stopped. The solution for me was to update my grub from `acpi_backlight=vendor` to `acpi_backlight=native`

0. Optional - backup grub `cp /etc/default/grub ~/backup-grub` You could also send it to another device in case you need to type it in during booting.
1. edit grub `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` replace the line for GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=Linux splash quiet pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=native"
```

2. Update grub `sudo update-grub`
3. Reboot

This restored all my brightness settings and controls including keyboard key controls.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

That could be an intentional change. Few people are go to hunt so deep to change brightness, so it makes sense to have the control just there under the system button in the top right corner.

Comment: Except there is now no UI to control keyboard backlight.  That is the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was not present for me, but just appeared on 12 sept 2022.

If you have an NVidia card, try disabling in your bios and switching to the CPU video.